# My angular component is not updated when using routerLink

Tags: angular, apollo-client, routerlink

I have the following problem: when I modify a field in the edit-conceptos component with the `<a href="conceptos/edit-conceptos/{{ concepto.id}}">` tag and return to the list-conceptos component, the changes are reflected, but this does not happen with **routerLink="../edit-conceptos/{{ concepto.id }}**.

I am consuming both the list service and the update service with apollo-client.

the following component takes care of listing

```
ngOnInit(): void {
this.conceptoService.getConceptos().
subscribe(
  (res) => {
    this.conceptos = [...res];
  }
  (err) => {
    console.log(err)
  }
)}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9rSF.png)

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way:

```
<a [routerLink]="[‘/edit-conceptos’, concepto.id]">
```

NOTE: Take a look of the typo in your image **"list-concetos"**, instead "list-conceptos"

Comment: Didn't work, thanks for the note

Answer (score 0):

The `routerLink` equivalent of `href` in your case would be:

```js
[routerLink]="['edit-conceptos', concepto.id]"
```